# Retrieving facebook profile infos with spring-security-oauth2-client

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

i'm trying to set up a project with facebook login and retrieve some profile infos of the users on connexion.

Context:

- Spring Boot : 2.0.0.RC1
- Spring Security Oauth2 Client : 5.0.2.RELEASE

Everything is working well and i'm able to connect users via facebook, **my problem is that facebook is retrieving me only the id (facebook id) and the name of the user**.
I would like to have much more infos from facebook on login like the profile url and the profile picture.

Security Config :

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

application.properties :

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.client-id=app-id
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.client-secret=app-secret
```

I even tried to add the scopes on the application.properties but nothing changed

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.scope=public_profile,email
```

In the facebook documentation they are saying that

> public_profile, user_friends and email are public scopes and they
>   dont need any verification

Any help on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Adding this property works for me:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.facebook.user-info-uri=https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email,picture
```